# Why am I not writing anything to my Roller2.raw?

Tags: c, fwrite, fread, imagefilter

I got the following code written in C but I have a small issue with this image filter program. The problem complies and everything as usual, but my image roller2.raw is not changing based on the number of iterations (checked in rawpixels.net). It is supposed to read the roller1 and write to roller2. Am I doing the writing in a wrong way? following code is below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef unsigned char image[251][256];

int main() 
{

 int h,i,j,k,l,sum,iterations;
 image *datain, *dataout;

 FILE *f , *g; 
 f = fopen("/home/osboxes/prestandaoptimering/roller1.raw", "r"); 
 g = fopen("/home/osboxes/prestandaoptimering/roller2.raw", "w"); 

 datain = (image*)malloc(sizeof(image));
 dataout = (image*)malloc(sizeof(image));
 fread(*datain, sizeof(image), 1, f); 


 printf("Enter number of iterations:");
 scanf("%d", &iterations);
 getchar(); 

 printf("Computing result\n");


 for( i = 0; i <= 250; i ++) {
        for( j = 0; j <= 255; j ++) {
                (*dataout) [i][j] = (*datain) [i][j]; 
    }
 }



 for( h = 1; h <= iterations; h ++) {

        for( i = 1; i <= 249; i ++) {

                for( j = 1; j <= 254; j ++) {

                        sum = 0;
                        for( k = -1; k <= 1; k ++) {
                            for( l = -1; l <= 1; l ++) {
                                sum = sum + (*datain)[i+k][j+l];
                }

                        (*dataout)[i][j] = (sum + (*datain)[i][j]*7) / 16;
            }
                }
                for( i = 0; i <= 250; i ++) {
                    for( j = 0; j <= 255; j ++) {
                        (*datain)[i][j] = (*dataout)[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
 }

 printf("Writing result\n");
 fwrite(dataout, sizeof(image), 1, g);
 if (f != NULL) {
    fclose(f); 
 }
 f = NULL;
 if (g != NULL) {
    fclose(g);
 }
 g = NULL;

 free(datain);
 free(dataout);
 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Start checking if `fopen` returns NULL. `fread(*datain, sizeof(image), 1, f);` -> `fread(datain, sizeof(image), 1, f);`. `(*dataout) [i][j]` is complete nonsense, you cannot access memory allocated with `malloc` as a 2D array, and anyway `(*dataout)` -> `(dataout)`. There are possibily other issues.

Comment: Check also the return values of your other function calls against the result expected for successful completion.  C standard library functions, especially I/O functions, are not silent when they are unable to do the job asked of them.

Comment: @MichaelWalz What's wrong with using `(*dataout)[i][j]`? `(*dataout)` is of type `unsigned char [251][256]`, so that looks fine to me.

Comment: It would be cleaner to replace `fread(*datain, sizeof(image), 1, f);` with `fread(datain, sizeof(image), 1, f);` since `datain` is a pointer to an `image`, but they should be the same value when converted to `void *` by the call to `fread`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I need the dataout aswell as well as the datain to be to be described as a pointer aswell.

Comment: I'd recommend opening the files in binary mode for portability to non Unix-like systems, by using modes "rb" and "wb" instead of "r" and "w" in the `fopen` calls.

Comment: If i cant access memory allocated with `malloc` as a 2D array, how can I do it in this situation?

Comment: @HaniMasta There is nothing wrong with your memory accesses.

Comment: What makes you thing the output image does not change depending on the number of iterations?

Comment: The Roller2.raw is supposed to be "blurred" when i upload it to rawpixels.net, but it is the same, Not really sure what the real problem is.

Comment: @HaniMasta Just a guess: `(*dataout)[i][j] = (sum + (*datain)[i][j]*7) / 16;` I think this line should be outside the `for( k = -1;..` loop.

Comment: @MayurK Thanks for the notification you are right! Still not getting the 'roller2.raw' burred though

Comment: @HaniMasta: As Michael Walz  mentioned, you need to change`(*data__)[i][j]` to `data__[i][j]`. Make this change everywhere and try.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in `iterations` loop.

```
for( h = 1; h <= iterations; h ++) 
{
    for( i = 1; i <= 249; i ++) 
    {
        for( j = 1; j <= 254; j ++) 
        {
            sum = 0;
            for( k = -1; k <= 1; k ++) 
            {
                for( l = -1; l <= 1; l ++) 
                {
                    sum = sum + (*datain)[i+k][j+l];
                }
            }

            //This should be outside the k and l loop.
            (*dataout)[i][j] = (sum + (*datain)[i][j]*7) / 16;
        }

        //You should use different variable name instead of i. OR declare 'i' again for `for` loop.
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 <= 250; i2 ++)
        {
            for( j = 0; j <= 255; j ++) 
            {
                (*datain)[i2][j] = (*dataout)[i2][j];
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: you are right about the sequence outside the k and l loop, but the two other foorloops should be inside the i loop

Comment: then you should use different variable names.

Comment: @HaniMasta: I have updated the answer. Please correct it if it is wrong. This might help someone someday. :)